# Why can't all admins see all components?

Tags: civicampaign

I have Civicampiagn installed and activated, and I can see it, but I have added a second admin and that account cannot see the link, nor can they see the campaign option on the add activity page.

What am I missing?  Kind regards~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable CiviCampaign you may need to visit your Permissions and give the CiviCampaign permission to the required roles.